# How to detect intersection between layers added from shapefile and manually drewn circles on the map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, arcgis, shapefile

I am trying to build a web app to show drones users the restricted areas where they can't fly, i am loading the map and those areas from shape files using leaflet.
Leaflet give me the ability to draw too.
When i draw for example a circle which make an intersection with a restricted area, i want to detect that and tell the user about that.
Is there any way to achieve this using leaflet by using a plugin or anything?
If not, is there any suggestions?

Comment: Might want to look at using turf.js library and methods like intersect()  https://turfjs.org/docs/#intersect

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for your reply, turf.js intersect() option works only with polygon. but i want detect intersections for every type of object (polygon,circle,line..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone still looking for something to solve this problem, here is the solution, it's [turf-boolean-intersect](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/tree/master/packages/turf-boolean-intersects)
And this is an example on how to use it:

```
var point = turf.point([2, 2]);
var line = turf.lineString([[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]);

turf.booleanIntersects(line, point);
//=true
```